# Clone local SVN checkout to GIT

Tags: svn, git

We have a remote SVN repository that is used to hold all our content form artwork to videos etc... As you would expect this remote SVN repository is 90 gigs in size.

I would like to use GIT instead of using SVN, considering I would like to have any updates or commits by anyone else in the team visible without needing to show history with SVN (This takes 5 minutes to do due to me working remotely.

I have a local SVN checkout of the repository on my machine and its 90 gigs in size. Is there any way I can use GIT to clone this SVN checkout (90 gigs of data) then continue to git svn fetch and pull/commit to the remote SVN repository without needing to clone the remote repository?

Please note, the SVN repository is 90 gigs in size. So doing a remote clone not is possible to the with Git Svn Clone. So I would like to somehow, duplicate the data and create the hash tables then somehow tell git "go now look for updates on the server at this revision"

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do this from what I could research. Your local SVN repository is different than a server's SVN repository that contains the whole history of the project, and modifications.

I got my work place to set me up a PC in their office in Europe where I've set GIT to do a clone of the repository (that is taking time). It seems this is the only effective way when dealing with large 20 to 60 gig repository that are on the opposite side of the world.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if GIT is very well suited for versioning big **binary** files (if I recall from some video presentation, even it's creator advocated against big binary files usage with GIT).

Comment: Thanks lonescu, though the biggest problem is that when working remotely SVN just takes too long to revert back and forward with file revisions. This is why I kind of need GIT. Or is there some tool out there that allows you to specify the revisions with SVN that caches the history locally without needing to go over the net?

Comment: The way GIT works is to always have a **complete** repository (90GB?). That's why is so fast, but again for non-binary content. 
I don't know of a tool that does what you need, but you could use a good SVN API to achieve that, or a simple enough SVN client using a good API, and than modify it to work the way you wish since from what I understand, the SVN protocol doesn't seem to forbid your scenario.